# Remote end closed connection without response chromedriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using chromedriver on selenium by python scripts.
When fire the scripts, 
`Remote end closed connection without response` was raised.

does anyone solve this?

chrome： 55.0.2883.28
chromedriver： 2.25

Comment: Try to update chromedriver. I have the same problem. It is solved by upgrading chromedriver to 2.28

Comment: How do you init your connection?

Answer (score -1):

I had issues with connections closing unexpectedly after updating to selenium 3.8.1, using Chrome and Java. I was able to resolve the issue by re-trying the driver setup when it quit unexpectedly.